# Layout multiple SwiftUI previews horizontally (or in grid) instead of vertically?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

When rendering multiple SwiftUI previous, they always render in a vertical stack. I would like to lay them out horizontally or ideally on a grid., because I have more horizontal space on my screen.

It's unproductive to have to keep scrolling up-and-down between multiple the previews, especially when you have more than two.

Anyone know a work around, or if it's possible?

Update:
E.g. As you see in the screen shot, I want to those two previews side by side horizontally.

Xcode Version 12.0 beta (12A6159)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this. This way it doesn't show iPhone borders but views render it as how it will look on iPhone 11 Pro screen.

```
struct SidebarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HStack {
            //... All your views ...
        }.previewLayout(.fixed(width: 375 * 2, height: 812))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Just replace the preview Group by an HStack, this way:

```
struct SidebarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            //... All your views ...
        }
        
    }
}
```

to:

```
struct SidebarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            //... All your views ...
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, this just seem to put two of views, side by side yes, but inside a single preview phone still.

Comment: I have the same issue. Seems a big oversight to not have this functionality.